# Оптимизация вывода из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.
Выдёргиваю запросом всего лишь одну запись из БД.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_zayv", $db) or die("error 3!");
$fio = mysql_result ($result,0,'fio');  //ФИО!
$cabinet = mysql_result ($result,0,'cabinet');
$messages = mysql_result ($result,0,'messages');
$date_time = mysql_result ($result,0,'date_time');
$ip_address = mysql_result ($result,0,'ip_address');
$status = mysql_result ($result,0,'status');
$description = mysql_result ($result,0,'$description');
```

Но чует моё серд... т.е. думает мой мозг, что тут как-то коряво это всё выглядит.
И ещё [тут указано про параметр field](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php), как его привинтить суда можно?
Примечание: В результате MySQL-запроса будет участвовать всегда только одномерный массив.

Comment: Запрос как запрос, единственное что добавлю:
> Использование «*» крайне не рекомендуется, поскольку постороннему читателю непонятно, что же за поля будут извлечены. Кроме того, так можно извлечь лишние поля (скажем, добавившиеся в ходе развития проекта), что повлечет ненужные расходы на их извлечение и хранение. При этом для наглядности не стоит еще забывать форматировать строку запроса для удобочитаемости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью согласен с [@naym](/users/11153/naym). Расширением mysql давно уже не рекомендуют пользоваться, а в версии PHP 5.5 оно отмечено как deprecated.
Но если задача не позволяет перейти на PDO или mysqli, то в данном случае реализация может выглядеть так:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_zayv", $db)
if (!result) {
    throw new \Exception('error 3!');
}

$data = current(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

В результате получим массив, ключами которого будут названия полей БД, а их значениями - соответствующие значения из таблицы

Answer (score 2):

Исполюзуйте PDO, очень мощная и удобная штука.

```
$db= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);   //подключение к базе
$query = "SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_zayv";
$res = $db->query($query)->fetchAll();//получение результатов
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php